# Hashtable words get overwritten in C

Tags: c, memory, dictionary, hashtable

I am working with hashtables for the first time and I think I have a basic understanding of how they work. I am using a hashtable to check to see if a word exists in a file. The program takes in a "dictionary" file and a word check file. The program works fine when I have a small dictionary but when I use a very large one, the words get overwritten. I was hoping to get some insight as to why. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "hashtable_constants.h"


#define HASH_SIZE 500
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 50

struct hashTable {
    int collisions;
    char** words;
};

struct hashTable hashTables[HASH_SIZE];

int hashKey(char * str)
{
    int key = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j <= 51; j++)
    {
        if(str[j] == '\0')
            break;

        key += (int)str[j];
    }
    key = key % HASH_SIZE;
    return key;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   

    if(argc > 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *dictionary = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *wordCheck = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    if(dictionary == NULL || wordCheck == NULL ) //ensure input file exists
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error accessing input files\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        hashTables[i].collisions = 0;
        hashTables[i].words = malloc(HASH_SIZE * MAX_WORD_SIZE);
    }

    struct stat fileStat1;
    struct stat fileStat2;

    stat(argv[1], &fileStat1);
    stat(argv[2], &fileStat2);

    char* dictBuffer = (char*)malloc(fileStat1.st_size + 1);
    char* wordCheckBuff = (char*)malloc(fileStat2.st_size + 1);

    if (dictBuffer == NULL || wordCheckBuff == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory error");
        return -1;
    }

    fread(dictBuffer, 1, (int)fileStat1.st_size, dictionary);
    fread(wordCheckBuff, 1, (int)fileStat2.st_size, wordCheck);

    char* word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1);
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)fileStat1.st_size; i++)
    {
        char c = dictBuffer[i];
        if(isspace(c))
        {
            word[count] = '\0';
            char* wordToAdd = word;
            int key = hashKey(wordToAdd);
            int collisionIndex = hashTables[key].collisions; 
            hashTables[key].words[collisionIndex] = wordToAdd;
            hashTables[key].collisions++;   
            count = 0;

            free(word);
            word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1);

            //printf("Added: %s to hashtable at key: %d\n",word,key);
        }
        else
        {
            word[count] = c;
            count++;
        }
    }

    count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)fileStat2.st_size; i++)
    {
        char c = wordCheckBuff[i];
        if(isspace(c))
        {
            word[count] = '\0';
            char* wordToCheck = word;
            int key = hashKey(wordToCheck);
            int collisionIndex = hashTables[key].collisions;
            int foundWord = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < collisionIndex; j++)
            {
                if(hashTables[key].words[j] == wordToCheck)
                {
                    printf("%s == %s\n",hashTables[key].words[j], wordToCheck);
                    foundWord = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(foundWord == 0)
                printf("Not a word: %s\n", wordToCheck);
            /*else
                printf("Key: %d -- Is a word: %s\n",key, word);*/

            free(word);
            word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1);
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            word[count] = c;
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
        free(hashTables[i].words);

    free(word);
    fclose(dictionary);
    fclose(wordCheck);      

    printf("done\n");

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On problem is that in the line:

```
hashTables[key].words[collisionIndex] = wordToAdd;
```

You add 'wordToAdd' to the table.

But wordToAdd is equal to word. A few lines later you call

```
free(word);
```

So the hash table now holds a pointer to freed memory.

This will lead to all sorts of undefined behaviour in the program, quite possibly seg-faults too. Also it's very likely that since the memory is now 'free', a subsequent call to malloc might return this same pointer again - which you will then fill with another word. Hence you see the overwriting of strings.

You need to review how you use 'malloc' / 'free' generally in the program. If you want a pointer to refer to a valid string, you cannot call 'free' on that pointer during the intended lifetime of that string.

What you want to do is malloc each string, and add the pointers to the hashtable. Then when you've finished with the hashtable, and no longer need the string data, then call 'free' on all the pointers contained within it. In your case, this will probably need to be in your cleanup code at the end of your program's execution.

Comment: +1 that iss definitely the problem. It that line should simply be `hashTables[key].words[collisionIndex] = word;` without the `free()` at all. in reality, this design is somewhat bass-ackwards, as memory should not even be *allocated* unless you know the word already. I.e. the first alloc outside the loop should't be there at all, and the one in the loop should be after finding the string content in the file buffer. *then* added to the hash table.

Comment: Thanks. Going from c# to c is a hard transition. so do I not need to allocate memory for the word that I am adding to the hash table?

Comment: You do need to allocate memory for each word you add, just don't free it till you've actually finished with it. Because there's no automatic memory management in C, you have to be very careful to understand the exact lifetime of each object. If you create a pointer, assign it to a block of memory, then store the pointer, you must not call 'free' on that pointer till you have REALLY finished with the data in that memory block.